# How to bundle my own images and call from function

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have built several custom add-ins for Powerpoint. I integrated them into PPT using [Custom UI Editor for Office](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor.htm).

As part of this process, I could make my own icons for buttons, simply by 'Inserting' my own `.png` files into the PPT (presumably somewhere in the backend, if I were to unbundle the `.zip.` file which every PPT actually is.

Now, I want to create a button that allows users to easily insert [country flag icons](https://www.flaticon.com/packs/countrys-flags), which I can obtain in `.svg` format. How can I bundle these `.svg` or `.png` files into PPT, and call them from a module?

(I don't think it's the calling from module I have trouble with - I just don't know how to bundle the image files into the PPT.)

---

**[EDIT]** Alternatively, what I'm asking is this: How can I create an 'Insert Icons' interface that looks like what you get from `Insert >> Icons`?

(update: John Korchok's answer has made clear this is not possible)

---

**[EDIT2]** If you rename your powerpoint from `.pptm` to ```` .zip```, you can see a folder inside the Zip file called ```ppt ````. Inside it, you get these folders:

[image]

Inside the `media` folder are EMF and WMF files created from pictures that were inserted into PPT (through the normal Insert Image function, or a simple Copy and Paste).

Is there a way I can write a function that calls images from within this folder?

Comment: The Insert icons command uses a Microsoft server to supply icons. They are not part of your installation. Programming something similar would not be easy, and would depend on 100% up-time on your server.

Answer (score 1):

There's no part of an Add-in where you might be able to store external files. I add a folder of images in the Add-ins folder, then create an installer that places the Add-in and folder in the correct locations.

You can also place the images on a web server and get PowerPoint to download them through VBA. Of course, you'll need a fast connection. The syntax looks like this:

```
    Dim oPicture As Shape
    Set oPicture = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture("http://www.brandwares.com/images/iconfile.png", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)
```

Comment: I've just edited my question after seeing your answer - is there a way to do what i'm asking now? (Internet is definitely not an option for this one)

Comment: What did you mean by "Add a folder of images in the Add-ins folder"?

Comment: I recommend you save as an add-in and examine the folder structure. There is no media folder and you can't add one. I'm not sure how I can express "Add a folder of images in the Add-ins folder" more clearly. Create a folder in the Addins folder, then put your images in there. Program your add-in to look in there for the images. You can use a relative path.

Comment: Apologies, I was being very stupid about that. However, the Add-in folder solution won't work, as I need to be able to distribute this modified PPT file. I've edited my question again (EDIT2) to make clear what I mean by the ```media``` folder - is there a way to leverage off this?

Comment: Are you distributing an add-in or a presentation? Or both? To access the media folder in a presentation, you would have to unzip it. It's simpler to place the images in the presentation and access them as shapes in VBA. You can't place a file in the media folder that doesn't display somewhere in the presentation.